# Unable to unzip .gz files in Apache HOP Workflow

Tags: airflow, unzip, orchestration

I have to unzip a .gz file in Apache HOP. I am using the unzip functionality but it only works well with .zip files and it's giving me the following error:

```
unable to get VFS File object for filename 'zip:file:///Users/kartikbhanot/Desktop/xyz/abc.json.gz' : 
Could not open Zip file "/Users/kartikbhanot/Desktop/qwr/abc.json.gz".
    2021/07/14 02:18:41 - Unzip the file - Could not open Zip file
```

HOP documentation on UNZIP is https://hop.apache.org/manual/latest/workflow/actions/unzip.html#top

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: A `gz` file is not a zip file. The link you provided suggests that the API you are using is for zip files only.

Answer (score 1):

for `gz` files you can use `gzip`:

```
gzip -d /Users/kartikbhanot/Desktop/qwr/abc.json.gz
```

As result you will get this file: `/Users/kartikbhanot/Desktop/qwr/abc.json`

Answer (score 1):

For future reference: Apache Hop uses Apache Commons VFS throughout all file facing features.  This means that you can read a GZipped file directly through a similar URL:

gz:file:///Users/kartikbhanot/Desktop/xyz/abc.json.gz

See here for more information:  https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/filesystems.html#gzip_and_bzip2